# Смена фона DIV при нажатии на ссылку

Tags: javascript

Есть ссылка:

```
<a href=# onClick="myFunc ()">ссылка</a>
```

Есть DIV:

```
<div id="MyElement" name="MyElement" style="background: url(content/!new/avto/1.jpg); width: 100px; height: 100px; background-size: cover;"></div>
```

Есть код javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunc () {
    document.getElementById("MyElement").style.backgroundImage = "img/666.png";
}
</script>
```

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на ссылку, фон дива менялся на нужный мне.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если в css прописать правило `backgroundImage:img/666.png;`, оно не сработает. Аналогично не работает и в js: надо писать `document.getElementById("MyElement").style.backgroundImage = "url(img/666.png)";`

Answer (score 1):

Вот, такой вариант должен сработать.
**CSS**:

```
#div{
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background-image: url("ford.jpg");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
   }
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="div" onclick="change(this);"></div>
```

**JS**:

```
function change(arg){
    arg.style.backgroundImage = "url('img.jpg')";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('link').onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById('myElement').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<a href="#" id="link">Link</a>
<div id="myElement" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;"></div>
```

Соответственно, backgroundColor можно заменить на backgroundImage и вставить нужный вам фон.